Maximal size of a family of incompatible partial finite functions with common domain size
Suppose $X$ is a set and $\{ a_i : i < M \}$ is a set of subsets of $X$, each of finite size $n$.  Suppose for each $i$, $f_i : a_i \to \{ 0,1 \}$ is a function, and for $i<j<M$, there is some $x$ such that $f_i(x) \not= f_j(x)$.
What is the largest possible value of $M$?  It should be $2^n$ as in the obvious case $|X| = n$, but I cannot formulate a proof.

Is $X$ finite? Is $n$ finite? Is $M$ finite?

@AsafKaragila I clarified that $n$ is finite.  I don't assume anything about $X$ or $M$.

@kodlu For each $i$ we assign a function $f_i$ with domain $a_i$ and codomain ${0,1}$.  I thought that was clear.

I wouldn't be surprised if there's a combinatorial proof that $M=2^n$ is the largest you can get by some counting argument, e.g. pick $a_0$, then find $n$ things which disagree on the various elements; then for each one of those find $n$ things which disagree with it, etc. and somehow concluding that if there are more than $2^n$ functions, then there will be one that is necessarily equal to another. Or some such.

When you say $f_i(x) \ne f_j(x)$, it implies that $x \in a_i \cap a_j$, right? Then I think you get an inequality $f(n) \le 1 + \sum_{k \ge 1} \binom{n}{k} f(n - k)$, by grouping by which $x \in a_0$ the other $a_i$ differ on and then for each group removing those $x$. Replacing by $f(n) \le 2^n f(n - 1)$ already gives $f(n) \le 2^{\sim \frac12 n^2}$.

A better upper bound using the inequality above is https://oeis.org/A000629

Measure theory to the rescue!
WLOG we can assume that $X$ is countably infinite (exercise).  Consider the Lebesgue measure on the Cantor space $2^X$.
Suppose we are given a family of partial functions each of size $n$ as hypothesized.  Each $f_i$ determines a basic clopen set $C_i$ of measure $2^{-n}$.  Since they pairwise disagree at some coordinate, these sets are pairwise disjoint.  Since the whole space has measure 1, there are at most $2^n$-many sets $C_i$.

This is great! Actually you don't even need measure theory beyond counting finite sets: by contradiction assume $M > 2^n$, pass to a finite subset still bigger than $2^n$, and then take $X = \bigcup a_i$, which is a finite union of finite sets hence finite. (I assume this is similar to the reduction to $X$ countable that you had in mind.)

Let's call a family of $f_i$ as above an $n$-family. Let us show by induction on $n$ that an $n$-family can't have size larger than $2^n$.
Suppose we know this is true for all $n<m$, but there is an $m$-family $\mathcal{F}$ of size $2^{m}$ and some $f \not\in \mathcal{F}$ with domain $\{x_n : n < m \}$ such that $\mathcal{F} \cup \{f\}$ still forms an $m$-familiy.
Consider $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{g \in \mathcal{F} : x_0 \not\in \operatorname{dom}(g) \vee g(x_0) = f(x_0)   \}$. Then note that $\vert \mathcal{F}_0\vert \geq 2^{m-1}$, because if $\vert \mathcal{F} \setminus \mathcal{F}_0 \vert > 2^{m-1}$, then $$\{ g \restriction (\operatorname{dom}(g) \setminus \{x_0 \} )  : g \in \mathcal{F} \setminus \mathcal{F}_0\}$$ is an $m-1$-family of size $>2^{m-1}$.
Now continue like this and define $\mathcal{F}_n = \{ g \in \mathcal{F}_{n-1} : x_n \notin \operatorname{dom}(g) \vee g(x_n) = f(x_n) \}$ and show that $\vert \mathcal{F}_n \vert \geq 2^{m-n}$.
After $m$ steps we have reached $\vert \mathcal{F}_m\vert \geq 2^0 = 1$. Let $g \in \mathcal{F}_m$. Then there should be $n$ so that $g(x_n) \neq f(x_n)$ but there isn't by construction.

Very nice.  But one thing-- Should you pick $F_0$ to be a subset of the set you defined of size exactly equal to $2^{m-1}$?  That way you can continue the induction and say $| F_0 \setminus F_1 | \leq 2^{m-2}$, etc.

I don't think it matters, does it? If a set has size at least $2^m$ and is partitioned into two subsets, one of the pieces has size at least $2^{m-1}$.

I must say I'm not 100% convinced by my own argument right now, since I don't see in the general case how to get the $m-n$-family if it is not guaranteed that all members of $\mathcal{F}{n-1}$ contain all $x_0, ..., x{n-1}$ in their domain.

On the first comment, you're right (oops). On the second, I tried to repair it but I messed up...

How do you get $|\mathcal{F}_1| \ge 2^{m - 2}$? You can't necessarily remove both $x_0$ and $x_1$ from the domains to get an $m - 2$ family since $x_0$ might not be in all the domains to begin with.
